# How To Monitor HTTP Request ,Response data?

Tags: httprequest, httpresponse

I have a Java EE Application ,Where i want to monitor some of my HTTP request response & I want to write those req,resp into a file.Also it should be in user control i.e When ever the user wants to monitor he can switch on/off in a application. How to do that?? There are several other tools which we can monitor ,but i don't want it manually.

Comment: Do you want to monitor requests from your application, or on the machine your application is running on? Either can require a different approach. Library advice is also offtopic for SO. You can search "http proxy library <your framework>" to find some suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide  some links so that i can setup

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a proxy server, like the infamous [Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) does. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm) is a small example.

You can also easily read the HTTP requests and responses in this manner, writing them to a file like you want.

Comment: Can i have  Burp Proxy server for windows and andriod both??

Comment: @RamL: you can get Burp to work on Android, if that's what you're asking. It's written in Java, after all.